# open camera using intent android 4.0?

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-camera-intent

i was trying to create an simple app that capture an image and send an email to the user.
It works fine < 4.0. but when i tested it on 4.0 and above version like htc me 4.03:

button click event to capture an image:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(new File(imagepath)));
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUREST);
```

and onActivityResult

```
Log.d("System out", "i am here..");
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUREST ){
            Log.i("System out","successfully captured an image");
        }
    }else{
        Log.i("System out","Cancel...");
    }
```

but when i click on button to capture an image onActivityResult code executed without waiting to capture or cancel image using intent.

while i tested the same app on i-tab(intex 4.03),it works fine.

is it device specific problem ? how could i resolve this problem ?

onActivityResult() CALLED before it returns RESULT_OK or CANCEL.

Thanks.